# Makefile rules to build a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, setuptools

I am building a python3 library inside another project that uses Makefile and I have a proper setup.py inside the lib.

I need to find a set of Makefile rules to build the package as a tarfile for distribution, obviously I am trying to find the proper steps to avoid rebuilding the package every time.

Something like:

```
dist/lib.tar.gz:
     ( cd lib && python3 setup.py bdist -d ../dist)
```

But I am trying to find the proper requirements for this rule so that it does not rebuild everytime

Lib looks like this

```
lib/setup.py
lib/lib/__init__.py
lib/lib/submodule/__init__.py
```

Comment: Why not handle it via dependencies?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you elaborate pls?

Comment: You add all the files the package depends on (in your case, the two `__init__.py`) as a dependency (behind the colon `:`) to the target. The command will only be executed when your target (`dist/lib.tar.gz`) is older than one of the dependencies. In your case you could simply add `: **/__init__.py`, so it updates whenever there is a `__init__.py` file in a subdirectory that is newer than the package.